# Access fields of class that's extended

Tags: scala

I have the following model:

```
abstract class Shape(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int)

case class Line(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int) extends Shape(x1, y1, x2, y2)

case class Rectangle(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int) extends Shape(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

I am doing this processing:

```
    val shapes: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Shape] = mutable.Queue.empty[Shape]
    shapes.foreach(shape => {
      (shape.x1 until shape.x2).foreach(x => if(0 <= x && x < canvas.width && 0 <= shape.y1 && shape.y1 < canvas.height) {
        board(x)(shape.y1) = 'X'
      })
    })
```

I am evaluating each `Shape` in the same way, regardless of whether it's a `Line` or `Rectangle`. However, I can't access the fields of an `abstract class`:

```
Error:(90, 14) value x1 is not a member of Shape
      (shape.x1 until shape.x2).foreach(x => if(0 <= x && x < canvas.width && 0 <= shape.y1 && shape.y1 < canvas.height) {
             ^
```

I would make `Shape` a `case class`, but then I wouldn't be able to extend it with `Line` and `Rectangle`.

What's the most elegant way of designing the model in this case?

I think I need to allow for:

- The extension of the base class.
- Accessing fields of the base class.

Comment: You are missing `val`s before `x`s and `y`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that construction parameters are not, by default, made available. What you need is this:

```
abstract class Shape(val x1: Int, val y1: Int, val x2: Int, val y2: Int)
```

But, wait! Why does this work then?

```
case class Line(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int) extends Shape(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

In the worksheet:

```
val line = Line(1,2,3,4)

(line.x1 until line.x2)  // Works!
```

The answer is that [case cases export their constructor parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html), which means they have automatically provided getter methods for those parameters. Normal classes do *not* do this, but by specifying `val` or `var` they will. Do not use `var` unless you expect those parameters to be mutable, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

In the `Shape` class, `x1`, `y1`, etc are not fields. They are constructor parameters. Prefix them with `val` to make them fields:

```
abstract class Shape(val x1: Int, val y1: Int, val x2: Int, val y2: Int)
```

Case class do that automatically, but you have to specify `val` for a non-case class.

Answer (score 2):

The fields `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` are just constructor parameters and are private. You could add `vals` to define public fields as well `Shape(val x1,...)`, define getters youself or use `case class` that would give you the getters and setters.